# How to be a good math teacher at a liberal art college?

Tags: undergraduate-education, usa

I am thinking of taking up a position at a liberal art college. I have taught mathematics at large public universities but I have no idea what is it like to work at a liberal art colleges. So what are things I should know about teaching mathematics at a liberal art college? Can you recommend some resources to read so I may be better prepared for this new job?

Comment: I'm skeptical that an answer that would be good for Guilford would be good for Carleton.

Comment: Do you have an _offer_ to teach at a specific place? Or is it that you imagine you'd _like_ such a position? As @AlexanderWoo comments, "liberal art[s] college" is not at all a tight identifier, in any case. Can you clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes, I do have an offer from a liberal art college.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me reply as someone who left a university in favor of a Liberal Arts College (LAC).
Although @AlexanderWoo's point is valid, my experience supports the following:

- At a LAC, the walls between the departmental silos are lower,
  enabling relatively easy cross-disciplanary collaborations.
- At a LAC with a strong faculty-governance tradition, you can play an
  all-college role that is almost impossible to achieve at a
  university.
- If you are passionate about teaching, it is uplifting to work at an institution
  that prioritizes and rewards teaching.
- I've found the engagement with students much more direct: There is less
  separation between students and faculty.
- The best students at a LAC are comparable to the best students at
  a university. So one can still research-collaborate with the top students.
- The scholarship that counts for tenure is more varied than at a university.
  For example, writing a textbook could gain you tenure at a LAC, but
  rarely at a university.

To counter-balance the above with two negative points:

- It rarely possible to remain active at the research-frontier of a popular math
  subdiscipline. You might need to adjust your research agenda toward less-traveled
  paths, and less-dependent on graduate students.
- The Univ$\to$LAC transition is nearly
  irreversible. It would not be easy to move from a LAC to
  a university later in your career.

Comment: The vibe I get from you is that a liberal arts college is a nice place, right?

Comment: Yes. But it depends on your inclinations: how much you value contributing on the frontier of research, compared to how much you value teaching.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Have you changed how you teach math in any way since moving to LAC?

Comment: @ablmf: Hmm. I don't think I changed how I teach, except that of course teaching graduate course is different from teaching undergraduate courses. But I taught/teach undergraduate courses more-or-less the same at the university as at the college.